# How to see Google Sheet add on history

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to see a log of who's installed add ons to a sheet? I don't mean the history of changes to the sheet itself, but possibly a more detailed log that shows when add ons were installed.

Comment: So far, I am not seeing any sources to find or show logs regarding the history of add-ons used in a sheet. Anyway, let's wait for other comments/answers as they might be able to provide information regarding your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Workspace Marketplace API can be used to list licensing notifications of an app that the developer owns.  An addon is an app with an app Id.
See documentation:
https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/reference/rest/v2/licenseNotification/list

You'll need the app Id to make the request to the Workspace Marketplace API.

The Google Workspace Marketplace API must be enabled.
Wait for the API to be available after you have enabled it.
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library?authuser=0&q=Workspace%20API

The app ID needed is listed in the App Configuration page of the Marketplace SDK.
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?authuser=0

[image: Enable API SDK]

Add the scope:
. . . . . /auth/appsmarketplace.license"
To the appsscript.json manifest file of the Apps Script project that the add-on is published from.

```
{
  "timeZone": "Etc/GMT",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license"],
  "runtimeVersion": "DEPRECATED_ES5"
}
```

The following code is an example.  Put it into the Apps Script project that is associated with the GCP project that the add-on is published from.

```
function getAddonInstallations() {
  var applicationId,maxResults,options,r,url;
  
  applicationId = "ENTER YOUR APP ID HERE";
  
  url = "https://appsmarket.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/" + applicationId;
  
  maxResults = 2;//Number of results to get
  
  if (maxResults) {
    url += "?maxResults=" + maxResults;
  }

  options = {};
  options.method = "GET";
  options.muteHttpExceptions = true;
  
  options.headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
  
  r = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
 
  Logger.log('r 22: ' + r)

}
```

Run the code.

Comment: Hi @AlanWells, glad to see someone answer this one as I am also wondering if it's possible.  Based on your statement `GCP project that the add-on is published from`, does this mean only the add-ons you published are applicable to the posted code and not other add ons you installed which were published by other users? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: You can't get information about other add-ons that you installed, that were published by someone else.  The only public information that I know of about add-ons is the number of installations that an addon has.  Which is shown on the Marketplace listing.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you so much!!